# Allow number to start with ZERO when stored in mysql text field

Tags: mysql

I need to store phone numbers starting with 0 but whenever i try to store this in MySql table the starting ZERO is removed because no number start with Zero actually
how i can solve this problem please do i need to change the field type from Integer to another type

Comment: i don't need to display the number. i need to store the numbers starting with zero. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Phone numbers are strings. So use a string data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the datatype to `unsigned-zerofill`. Refer the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

or you can use the [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function as well like

```
SELECT LPAD( yourNumber, lengthOfYourNumber, '0')
```